# Header column sorting in dgv, deletes all checkboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkbox

When I use sorting (header column) in datagridview, all rows that were previously checked became unchecked. Why is this happening?

Is there a way to prevent unchecking checkboxes on sorting with header column?

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything about unchecking checkboxes (on sorting). I'd like to know if someone has any idea what could I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you rebind your datagridview without selected datas so you erase , you must persist your selected datas